# Haskell pairing elements of a single list

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

Is there a way to pair elements up in a single list like this:

change `[cat,dog,bird,rabbit]` to `[(cat,dog),(bird,rabbit)]`

I know of the `zip` function but it combines two lists, how can I do this for one list?

Comment: What should your function do if the list you pass it has an odd number of elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach to use `zip` is to zip the even-positioned elements of our list with the odd-positioned elements list:

```
takeEveryN :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
takeEveryN _ [] = []
takeEveryN n (x:xs) = x : takeEveryN n (drop (n - 1) xs)

zipList :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
zipList xs = zip (takeEveryN 2 xs) (takeEveryN 2 (drop 1 xs))
```

Comment: never use `tail`, use `drop 1` instead. :) `tail` will error on empty lists, `drop 1` won't.

Comment: to your other question, you can use this answer with `zipWith f` instead of `zip`.